# How to Sort an Array by the Property of a Class?

Tags: javascript

How to sort products created in the "Product" class and recorded in the "Shop" class at a price in order of growth.The essence of the method consists in sorting by price (with the ability to set the order) sortByPrice (order)

## Call example:

console.log (shop.sortProductsByPrice (Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC));

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }
    //method for sorting the product at its price
    sortProductsByPrice(dataset, order, prop) {
        let sorted = dataset.sort((a, b) => {
            let innerA;
            for (let subObjectName in a) {
                let inner = a[subObjectName];
                innerA = inner;
                break;
            }
            let innerB;
            for (let subObjectName in b) {
                let inner = b[subObjectName];
                innerB = inner;
                break;
            }
            return order(innerA[prop], innerB[prop])
        });
        return sorted;
    }
}

const shop = new Shop();
// create products
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 2", 1, 700));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 3", 2, 800));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 4", 3, 1000));
//sort by the specified key "price"
let res = shop.sortProductsByPrice(shop.products,
    (a, b) => a - b, "price");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the for... in iteration. I don't think it's doing what you mean for it to be doing.

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }
    //method for sorting the product at its price
    sortProductsByPrice(dataset, order, prop) {
        let sorted = dataset.sort((a, b) => {
            
            return order(a[prop], b[prop])
        });
        return sorted;
    }
}

const shop = new Shop();
// create products
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 2", 1, 700));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 3", 2, 800));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 4", 3, 1000));
//sort by the specified key "price"
let res = shop.sortProductsByPrice(shop.products,
    (a, b) => a - b, "price");
console.log(res);
```